# MassTransmit/RabbitMQ multiple distinct instances on the same machine

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I was wondering if it is possible to run multiple MassTransmit or RabbitMQ instances on the same server.  Basically we have a .net app using MassTransmit on top of RabbitMQ.   Unfortunately a lot of our clients run both live and test environments on the same server so in order to deploy to the real world we need a way of having either multiple instances or the ability to segregate messages between live and test.

A few ideas I've had
1) Do something like: https://lazareski.com/multiple-rabbitmq-instances-on-1-machine/
The problem here is it relies on a lot of config on clients sites.

2) I could include a header in all messages and each consumer checks for the present of the correct header before consuming the message (e.g. header has 'live' or 'test'.) Obviously this means all messages being received from all instances whether they are meant for them or not which is far from ideal.

Ideally I would like to be able to do something with minimal setup on a clients site, like a virtual sub instance or directory for each environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to work around this issue.

The first way is the most obvious - you need to use virtual hosts.

From the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/vhosts.html):

> Virtual hosts provide logical grouping and separation of resources.
>   Separation of physical resources is not a goal of virtual hosts and
>   should be considered an implementation detail.

Create two virtual hosts in your RMQ instance, called `test` and `prod` and the only thing you would need to do on MassTransit side is to change the RMQ connection string:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/test"), host =>
    {
        host.Username("username");
        host.Password("password");
    });
});
```

So you will use `rabbitmq://localhost/prod` for production. Naturally, those values should not be hard-coded but come from the configuration.

I believe that virtual hosts cover your needs entirely.

If you really need to run the test environment completely separated, you can just run it in a Docker container. This option will give you the ability to kill the whole thing and start from scratch when you need a clean environment. You can easily remap default ports to avoid conflicts with the production instance:

```
docker run -d --name test-rmq -p 5673:5672 -p 8080:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

If you run the command above, the new instance will be accessible via AMQP on `localhost:5673` and the management plugin will be on `http://localhost:8080`